# Tool to import Jira Server issues into Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps, google-drive, jira

I want to import Jira ticket information from a self-hosted Jira Server into Google Sheets using a JQL query (e.g., `"Epic Link" = "PROJECT-ISSUEID" AND status not in (Done, In Review, In Progress, Blocked)`)- essentially what [Jira Cloud for Sheets](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-work-management/docs/use-jira-cloud-for-sheets/) accomplishes, but for Jira Server. I would like to do this without manual export/import from Jira Server.

Is there an existing automated solution, a way to adapt Jira Cloud for Sheets to serve this purpose or a straight-forward-ish way to roll my own similar integration that lets me import some data (issue ID, link, assignee, status, dates, priority, and labels) from Jira into a spreadsheet?

I am open to something manual but would prefer something fully automated, especially if there's a way for me to do this in Apps Script myself (if anyone knows where to start for a Jira integration in Apps Script).